# How to send a page link as a parameter in google analytics API and retrieve the report data using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics-api

I am new in [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

I need to pass a page url**(localhost/controller/action)** to Google Analytics by using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/).

I have been unable to find the correct way of doing this in the Google Analytics API documentation.  How do I pass a page URL to that API.

Any suggestion or answer is highly appreciable.

Comment: Have you checked the articles and code samples on the [Google Analytics API website](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/)?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) is only for **Reading** information you don't actually uploaded anything to it.  With the exception of [daily uploads](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads) which I suspect isn't what you are after.

I think what you are looking for is the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) which will allow you to add data to Google analytics in a similar way that the JavaScript Web Tracking snippet does.   Unfortunately Google hasn't released a client library to help you do this with C#.  Its not that hard to work out its a simple http POST or GET and the info is up.